# My CNN seems to be forgetting weights after training is completed?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using a model that consists of partiall frozen ResNet50, a deep layer, and some other stuff, as seen [here](https://github.com/noelcodella/tripletloss-keras-tensorflow/blob/master/tripletloss.py#L74). When training, I get an accuracy of about 0.7. However, if I try predicting the training set, my accuracy drops to about 0.54. Moreover, if I only take 10% of my training set, I get 0.5 accuracy when predicting my testset sometimes, and other times the correct 0.72 or so. But with the real training set, it is always around 0.5. Is there anything that might be causing this, or a way to prevent this? Or am I doing something wrong? I have not touched the shuffling parameter, and I made sure to use .fit_generator and later .predict_generator.

Comment: Can you show the code?